# Change Default Audio Output

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I recently bought an Audio interface to use with my microphone for recording. When I restart my computer, it automatically uses the output of my audio interface, instead of my headphones. I don't have my headphones plugged into the audio interface, just into the headphone jack on the computer. I'm able to hear sound from my headphones, but I can't adjust the volume. So I have to open up the sound settings on Linux, and change the output back to my headphones. Then it works fine. The Problem is that I have to do this every single time I turn on or reboot my computer. Is there a way to set my Headphones to be the default Audio output? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

**My OS: Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
1. Run: 'pactl list short sinks';
2. Note the device name you want to use by default;
3. Run: 'pactl set-default-sink <Your_Device_Name>';
4. Open the application "Startup Applications";
5. Click on "Add";
6. Give your startup item a name;
7. Copy your command from above and paste it into the command field: 'pactl set-default-sink <Your_Device_Name>';
8. Click on "Save".
```

Your default audio device will be set on each boot and as such be persistent.

Alternatively, just add the third command to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I use the Startup Applications for some other things as well, so I thought that I might be able to do it through that, but I had no idea what the command was. Thanks again!  : )

Comment: @RyanKingArt No problem, have a lovely day or evening!